# Delete register with a stored procedure with foreign key

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, cascading-deletes

Im new with SQL Server, i have programmed several stored procedures and i have the next problem. For example, i have 2 tables (Role and User), and when i try to delete a role, logically the procedure shows me the error (547) because there are a foreign key on "User Table". So, what i need is finding a way to delete that role. If it would be necessary delete all the user whose role is that i gonna delete or if its possible to reassigne a new role for that user who belongs to the role which i wanna delete.

I hope you understand what i want to do more or less. I search a simple example how to do that.

Thanks!

Comment: And what is your problem?  Delete users with that role or update with different role first and then delete role

Comment: How is the best way to delete the list of users who belongs that role I wanna delete, because on the "User" table there is a foreign key "role_id".

Answer (score 0):

Deleting users with role 5:

```
Delete From Users Where RoleID = 5
```

Or updating:

```
Update Users Set RoleID = 6 Where RoleID = 5
```

Then deleting role itself:

```
Delete From Role Where ID = 5
```

Comment: Ok, i think that I understood it! Thanks!